# in spring mvc fm, How can i decide the return type depend on arguments?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

the problem is :

i have a controller `return Object` **ModelAndView(forward a view)**, and another controller have no `return type (void)`, (i use ajax to write response directly.)

but both two controller have same called.and work the same thing.
so, i need fix them and write gather.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?your question is not very clear.

Comment: i need write them in just one controller, but i don't know what the return type is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have return type void and use request dispatcher to forward a view

```
  RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.html");
  rs.forward(request,response);
```

And in second case you simply write your response to output stream.